# Is using a static property in a form bad practice knowing that there's only one instance of the form?

Tags: c#, static

In a complex form, I have a property called `Readonly` that determines if everything is editable or not.  So far, I'm passing this property to every sub custom control in this form by constructor, and in other places, I access the form itself to get the value.

But this is quickly becoming too complex.
I'm thinking of making this property **Static** in the form knowing that there's only one instance of this form in the application.

Is it OK to use this property as a static in this case? Or it's a bad practice even there's only one instance of the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply ask yourself: does this relate to the *form* or to the *type* of form. Hypothetically, if there were more than one form - would they all be readonly/not at the same time? Or would it be per form?

Then: you have the answer. I suspect it should be instance (non-static).

Comment: Actually it's related to the form and converting it to static just to simplify dealing with it instead of passing it (or access to it) everywhere.

Comment: @FrenchBoy sounds like doing something ugly to be lazy, IMO

Comment: @FrenchBoy well, it'll probably *work*, but that doesn't make it a great idea - in particular from a maintenance and testing perspective

Answer (score 4):

Even if your have a single instance of the form using a static field doesn't make it safe. You could have multiple threads that cause problems. Not to mention the difficulty to unit test your application. Personally I try to avoid static fields as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative solution:

1. Add the controls to your form as usual
2. Create an interface called `IReadOnlyToggable` which has a `IsReadOnly` property and let the form implement it.
3. Add the following property to your custom controls:

code:

```
public bool IsFormReadOnly
{
    get 
    {
        var form  = ParentForm as IReadOnlyToggable;
        return form != null && form.IsReadOnly;
    }
}
```