# Is it a bad idea to give a C# form a static property pointing to the only instance of the same form?

Tags: c#, winforms, static

I have a fairly simple application that monitors folder activity and logs it on a server.
In this application I start off with a Form object called Form1. On this form I have a NotifyIcon. Because I need to change the text in the BalloonTip of the NotifyIcon from different Forms along the way, I was thinking of setting a static property of Form1 that will point to the only instance of Form1. This is how it would look in my oppinion:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private static Form1 staticRef;
    // Other private properties

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        staticRef = this;
        // Rest of constructor logic
    }
    public static void changeNotifyBalloonText(String newText, int timeInMillis)
    {
        if (staticRef != null && staticRef.notifyIcon1 != null)
        {
            staticRef.notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = newText;
            staticRef.notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(timeInMillis);
        }
    }
    // Rest of public and private methods
}
```

Other things to be noted:

a. There will never be more than 1 instance of Form1.

b. I always check the value of staticRef against null, before trying to use it.

c. I cannot afford to make a temporary, local instance of Form1 just to set a BalloonTip message.

d. This solution works very well, i'm more interested in knowing if it's "too hacky" and if so - what would be a better approach to my issue?

e. The closest thing I've found that may answer my question (about static properties) to some degree is here:
[Is using a static property in a form bad practice knowing that there's only only one instance of the form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292054/is-using-a-static-property-in-a-form-bad-practice-knowing-that-theres-only-one)

Comment: What you've done is a **bad implementation of the singleton pattern**, since the form's constructor is public. However, I'm not sure there is a reason to use a singleton pattern here, I think that using `this.notifyIcon1` instead of `staticRef.notifyIcon1` would be sufficient. Should you choose to use the singleton pattern, read [this article](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx) by jon skeet first.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Thanks for the info and reference. The `this.notifyIcon1` approach fails due to the static context of the method, as noted by Jon as well. Only writing this here for future readers that may wonder the same thing. In the end i believe i will be using a Singleton while keeping in mind certain aspects that are detailed in your reference link. Thank you once more!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have here is a form of the singleton pattern.

The singleton pattern certainly has its detractors and its defenders (google "singleton anti-pattern").

It is though a very convenient way of doing this.

I would recommend an approach like either::

1. Create a class that represents operations on a notify icon.
2. Have that class as the only class that accesses `staticRef.notifyIcon1`.
3. Have it do so as a reference to `notifyIcon1`, not as `Form1`.
4. Have a static method or property that gets the icon-controlling class.

Or:

1. Simply have a static method or property that returns the `NotifyIcon` object.
2. Make it the only method that accesses the static reference to the form.

The advantage of one over the other is around whether you want to expose the full interface of `NotifyIcon` or provide a set of operations that make sense to your application.

This way you are still using the singleton pattern, but in restricting the way that it is accessed the fact that there is global state has less of a global impact, relates more directly to the purpose of that global state (the icon itself), and is more readily extended to different uses. e.g. if you some day need to have two icons, you change the method that static method or property to one that does a lookup of some sort, and change all the current calls to use the key for the first icon. Meanwhile, implementation changes up to and including completely changing which form provides that icon can be done quickly in one place.

Comment: Actually, what he has is a **bad implementation of the singleton pattern**, since the form's constructor is public. However, I'm not sure there is a reason to use a singleton pattern here, I think that using `this.notifyIcon1` instead of `staticRef.notifyIcon1` would be sufficient.

Comment: @ZoharPeled the problem then is finding the form to call the method on, from outside that instance.

Comment: Opps, you are correct, i didn't noticed that the method is static... forget about the `this` part, it's still not quite a singleton pattern.

Comment: @ZoharPeled yes, but I think it's close enough that looking at singleton, arguments for and against, and views on how best to implement it will inform. Part of the point of patterns is that "this is a bit like..." can be as useful a thought as "I will use...".

Comment: @JonHanna, Zohar Peled
Thank you both for your answers. I had not heard of Singleton patterns but have since looked a bit into this matter and why they are "hated". They seem to have quite a few flaws but for my particular case, i still feel they are a potentially valid solution. Granted - i'll need to look into something closer to what is not considered a "bad implementation" and use them at an absolute minimum but the general vibe i got from your answers and following research tells me it's not as big of a bad practice as i've initially thought it was. Once more - thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think your current design is tightly coupled to other classes sending the notification and it requires your form to be a single instance as well.

You can decouple this a great deal by using an event broker to send the notification to any interested parties. Many frameworks have event brokers, I have used one from Prism but there are others as well.

Your code will then only know about the event broker and what events your class is interested in.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private static IEventBroker eventBroker;
    // Other private properties

    public Form1(IEventBroker eventBroker)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.eventBroker = eventBroker;

        this.eventBroker.Register<NotifyBaloonText>(changeNotifyBalloonText);

    }

    public static void changeNotifyBalloonText(NotifyBaloonText args)
    {
        notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = args.NewText;
        notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(args.TimeInMillis);
    }
    // Rest of public and private methods
}
```